# Correct way to concate dependecy scripts for Angular2 project?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `grunt` to manage my Angular2 project and the first step is to concate all dependency files into one file. Currently I am using the following list of external dependencies:

```
node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js
node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js
node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js
node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js
```

This is for `angular2@^2.0.0-beta.0`. It seems to work as I can launch my app. But since there are many breaking changes in recent updates, I wonder if I am including correct dependency files and load them in a correct order.

Comment: You want to look at node packages such as JSPM or Webpack.  They will help you bundle all the various dependencies that make up your app (and exclude those you don't need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @brando,I finally use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to help me handle the dependency management. Considering the module definition and file structure of Angular2 changes frequently, it's better to avoid any manual management.